# Issue with executing multiple executeQueryAsync is JSOM

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-addin, visual-web-part, jsom, 2016

I am trying to create a web part in SP 2016 where the web part contains 2 custom properties, site URL and calendar name (list name) present in that URL. I am trying to read the 2 properties, load the calendar present in the site URL and read all the events for the current week present in the calendar.

I have created the custom properties, able to read the properties in JSOM which is a promise. executeQueryAsync is not working which is a success call back of the getSiteUrl promise.

This is what I have right now.

```
    function getSiteUrl() {  //This fn reads the 2 custom properties
        var dfd = $.Deferred(function () {
            var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
            var web = context.get_web().getFileByServerRelativeUrl(_spPageContextInfo.serverRequestPath);
            var webPartManager = web.getLimitedWebPartManager(SP.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.shared);
            var webPartDefs = webPartManager.get_webParts();
            context.load(webPartDefs, 'Include(WebPart.Properties)');
            context.executeQueryAsync(
                function () {
                    // Successfull
                    var site = {};
                    for (var i = 0; i < webPartDefs.get_count() ; i++) {
                        var webPartDef = webPartDefs.getItemAtIndex(i);
                        var webPart = webPartDef.get_webPart();
                        var properties = webPart.get_properties();
                        if (properties.get_fieldValues()['Title'] == 'DAIDS Calendar') {
                            site.SiteFullUrl = properties.get_fieldValues()['SiteFullUrl'];
                            site.calendarName = properties.get_fieldValues()['calendarName'];

                        }
                    }

                    dfd.resolve(site);
                },
                function (sender, args) {
                    // Failure
                    dfd.reject(args.get_message());
                });
        });
        return dfd.promise();
    }

    function intialize() {
        var siteUrl = getSiteUrl();

        siteUrl.done(function (site) {// site has the 2 custom properties

            var request = {};
            request.calendarName = site.calendarName;
            request.siteUrl = site.SiteFullUrl;
            var ctx = new SP.ClientContext(request.siteUrl);
            var list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(request.calendarName);

            request.query = new SP.CamlQuery();
            request.query.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><DateRangesOverlap>' +
 '<FieldRef Name=\"EventDate\">' + 
'</FieldRef><FieldRef Name=\"EndDate\"></FieldRef>'
 +'<FieldRef Name=\"RecurrenceID\"></FieldRef><Value Type=\"DateTime\">' +
'<Week/></Value></DateRangesOverlap>' + 
'</Where></Query></View>');
            request.itemCollection = list.getItems(request.query);
            ctx.load(request.itemCollection, 'Include(Title,EventDate, Description, EndDate)');
            console.log("Testing..."); //This is getting printed out.
            ctx.executeQueryAsync(function () {
                var listEnumerator = request.itemCollection.getEnumerator();
                var calendarEvents = [];
                while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                    var oListItem = listEnumerator.get_current();
                    calendarEvents.push({
                            Title: oListItem.get_item('Title'),
                            EventDate: oListItem.get_item('EventDate'),
                            Description: oListItem.get_item('Description'),
                            EndDate: oListItem.get_item('EndDate')
                        });
                    });
                }
                console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.calendarEvents));

            },
        function (sender, args) {
            console.log("Inside fail function");
            console.error(args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
        });

        });

        siteUrl.fail(function (result) { 
            var error = result;
            console.log(error);
        });
    }

    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', intialize);
```

Output:
Inside fail function

Unexpected response data from server.

null

Any thoughts on why this is not working?

**EDIT (11/22/2016) :**

I tried debugging the code where it reads the calendar events. I tried to hard code the URL and the calendar name and I am assuming that's where the problem is.

The code segment

```
var context = new SP.ClientContext('/gallery/Pages/events');
var list = context .get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Calendar');
```

is not working while if I have a calendar in the same page the below code is working fine.

```
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = context.get_web();
var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle('Calendar');
```

Is the URL syntax used is correct? I also tried using

```
var context = new SP.ClientContext(_spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl + '/gallery/Pages/events');
```

But no luck so far.

Comment: Is your siteurl correct ? request.siteUrl = site.SiteFullUrl; Are you trying to get data from other site collection or subsite ?

Comment: @SiddharthVaghasia Yes! I am trying to get data from another subsite!

Comment: @SiddharthVaghasia This is what the url parameter is '/gallery/Pages/events.aspx' I tried without '.aspx' as well. Do you think this is correct?

Comment: @gilango yes the URL is wrong, you are supposed to use relative url or absolute url to the site. You are now using the URL to a page.aspx. Remove /Pages/Events

Answer (score 0):

Your JSOM seems okay (at first glance), so test the content

Trim this:

```
 request.query.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><DateRangesOverlap>' +
    '<FieldRef Name=\"EventDate\">' + 
    '</FieldRef><FieldRef Name=\"EndDate\"></FieldRef>' +
    '<FieldRef Name=\"RecurrenceID\"></FieldRef><Value Type=\"DateTime\">' +
    '<Week/></Value></DateRangesOverlap>' + 
    '</Where></Query></View>');
```

to:

```
 request.query.set_viewXml('<View><Query></Query></View>');
```

then one-by-one extend the Query

Comment: I tested the query itself which works fine.